# Sending a notification through Wifi network to Smartphones

Tags: android, iphone, wifi, smartphone

I have a store and want to know if it is possible  through wifi or other means, sending a notification to consumers connected to my network with smartphones

Comment: No. There is no messanger thing running on phones that can respond.

Comment: check ip messenger for android.